# two submit buttons from one form laravel php

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I want to use two submit buttons in one form. 
this is my blade file

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" id="pay" name="Pay Now" value="Pay ">
```

This is the way I have declared the function in the controller

```
 public function postAuth()
    {  
        if(Input::get('submit')) {

            $this->postSubmit(); 
        } elseif(Input::get('pay')) {

            $this->postPay(); 
        }

    }

    public function postSubmit()
    {
        echo "We're logging in";
        return Redirect::to('/Admin/channel');
    }

    public function postPay()
    {
        echo "We're registering";
        return Redirect::to('/pay');
    }
```

this is my web.php

```
Route::post('/abc', 'channelController@postAuth');
```

but there's an issue with my controller function.. how should i correct it?

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: this function is not calling
    //check which submit was clicked on
        if(Input::get('submit')) {
            return "dfgcvhbj";
            $this->postSubmit(); //if login then use this method
        } elseif(Input::get('pay')) {
            return "sdfsdfs";
            $this->postPay(); //if register then use this method
        }

Comment: Do not use comments for adding such details — edit your post and use proper formatting for code, as comments are not well suited for that.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov : He can **not** do it with 21 reputation score ;-).

Comment: @AlexandreT The question author can do whatever he/she wants with their own post (with few exceptions, like deleting an upvoted question already having good answers).

Comment: Oh! My mistake. Sorry! I though he can not! Thanks @AntonSamsonov

Answer (score 3):

Try as below...

HTML

```
 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="send">
  <input type="submit" id="pay" name="submit" value="pay">
```

Function

```
 public function postAuth()
    {   //return "dfsdf";
        //check which submit was clicked on
        if(Input::get('submit') == 'send') {
            return "dfgcvhbj";
            $this->postSubmit(); //if login then use this method
        } elseif(Input::get('submit') == 'pay') {
            return "sdfsdfs";
            $this->postPay(); //if register then use this method
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes according to the way you have mentioned the functions are calling. But not redirected to the blade files. Suggest me a way, is there any syntactical error?

Comment: see your `routing`.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the controller as shown below

```
public function postAuth()
    {
        if (Input::get('submit') == 'send') {

            return redirect(url('/Admin/channel'));
        } elseif (Input::get('submit') == 'pay') {

            return redirect(url('/pay'));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can use jQuery validator .You can download : https://plugins.jquery.com/validation/

Then you can remove  tag and use .

in submitHandler

```
        submitHandler: function (form) {
                                  var loading_el = $('#pay');
```